# NPE when referring to application resources

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, applet, embedded-resource

I am trying to display an icon on a button using the code posted below. But at run time, the console shows an NPE and highlights the code posted despite I am sure that the icon I wish to display on the button is placed in that path.

Note: the `..` in the path is just a short for writing the whole path.

#### Code

```
ImageIcon iconplay = new ImageIcon (ClassLoader.getSystemResource("L:\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Play.png"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is not a system resource, so don't try to use the system class loader.  Something more like the following will use the **context class loader.**:

   ```
   URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");
   ```
2. That path starting with a drive letter is wrong.  It should be a path relative to the class-path.

Comment: [This is not a system resource, so don't try to use the system class loader.]=> what should i use then

Comment: See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info)..